# Prove: $A, B, C$ are different points. If $C \in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$ then $\overleftrightarrow{CA}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and...

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

Prove: $A, B, C$ are different points. If $C \in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$ then $\overleftrightarrow{CA}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CB}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.

I'm not sure about this proof, it reads so evidently.

Proof:

If $C \in \overleftrightarrow{AB}$ then we have this options:

1) $C$ is between $A$ and $B$. Since $C$ is between $A$ and $B$, the three points are colinear and the lines $\overleftrightarrow{AC},\overleftrightarrow{CB},\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ are the same. Therefore $\overleftrightarrow{CA}=\overleftrightarrow{CB}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$

2) $A$ is between $C$ and $B$. Since $A$ is between $C$ and $B$, the three points are colinear and the lines $\overleftrightarrow{CA},\overleftrightarrow{AB},\overleftrightarrow{CB}$ are the same.Therefore $\overleftrightarrow{CA}=\overleftrightarrow{CB}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$

3) $B$ is between $C$ and $A$. Same reasoning...

This is good?

Edit 1: Also I can use contradiction and I don't have to consider the other 2 cases.

Comment: I would think that this is easier: $\overleftrightarrow{CA}$ is a line which contains $A$ and $C$ (by definition), and $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ is a line which contains $A$ and $C$ (by definition and assumption). Since for each pair of distinct points there is a unique line which contains both of them, we must have $\overleftrightarrow{CA}=\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.

Comment: Don't need to consider the three options  if $C \in AB$ then the three points are colinear no matter what order they are in.  And that's it, you are done.

Comment: Actually that's what I thought at first but consider it too simple.